# How to make @connect decorator work with redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Is there any good practice on how to combine using `connect` from `react-redux` as decorator with `redux-saga`?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@connect(({ data }) => ({ data }), require('../models/effects').default)
export default class User extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    console.log('on click.');
    // how to make redux-saga work here?
    this.props.action1();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redux-saga turns redux *`actions`* into side effects, while react-redux's `connect` pulls fields out of the *`store`* and exposes them to your component as props.

To put it another way, you don't need to connect your component to redux-saga directly.  Instead, produce actions as you would if you were not using redux-saga.  Then add sagas that react to those actions and perform the necessary side-effects, producing new actions when those side effects are complete.  Your reducers should handle those final actions to update the state, which will trigger `connect` and update your components.